# ¿Cómo puedo llenar un select de HTML5 con datos que llegan de la base de datos en angular?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

Buenas tardes estoy creando un formulario angular 14 y necesito que select pero sus opciones se llenan con datos que vienen por una consulta de base de datos y viene de esta forma

```
[
 {
  "nombre": "devNoob",
  "value": 10
 },
 {
  "nombre": "devNoob2",
  "value": 11
 }
]
```

y de esta forma tengo que llenar mi select, esto fue lo que hice en un principio

```
datosSelect: Object;

llenarDatosSelect():void {
    const datosArr: Array<Object> = respuesta /*respuesta serian los datos de la DB*/
    datos.push(obj => {
        this.datosSelect = obj;
    })
}
```

pero en el HTML no se que poner para que esto funcione intente hacer esto

```
<select>
    <option value="{{datosSelect.value}}">{{datosSelect.nombre}}</option>
    <option value="{{datosSelect.value}}">{{datosSelect.nombre}}</option>
    <option value="{{datosSelect.value}}">{{datosSelect.nombre}}</option>
    <option value="{{datosSelect.value}}">{{datosSelect.nombre}}</option>
</select>
```

pero a ver... primero no se cuantos datos vendrán esto puede variar aparte no se porque pensé que esto me iba a funcionar jajajajja :V, gracias por su ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buenas tardes @devNoob para hacer esto necesita hacer un ciclo repetitivo, angular tiene una solución para esto y es el *ngFor
bueno primero que todo no es necesario acceder al Array o a tu arreglo y extraer los objetos, entonces el código quedaría así

```
datosSelect: Array<Object>;

llenarDatosSelect():void {
    this.datosSelect: Array<Object> = respuesta /*respuesta serian los datos de la DB*/
}
```

en el HTML solo harías esto, no es necesario hacer un option por cada objeto

```
<select>
    <option *ngFor="let element of datosSelect" value="{{element.value}}">{{element.nombre}}</option>
</select>
```

y listo al ejecutar la funcion este creara los options que sean necesarios, espero haberte ayudado :D.
para mas información consulta la documentación del [*ngFor](https://angular.io/api/common/NgFor) de angular